# iwd opc proceed to checkout missing on cart [Magento 1.9]

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

I Was using native onepage checkout of magento 1.9 till now. Came across IWD OPC and thought of integrating it. Features, for a free extension, are great.

After installation, everything worked well with admin side. But the on the cart page, frontend, I **could not see the "proceed to checkout" button.**

I checked **/template/checkout/cart.phtml** and found nothing.

tried to google the issue but couldn't find exact issue. Is there anyone whoo has come across such issue? If yes, did you resolve it? If yes, what did you do to make it work?

### [UPDATE][SOLVED]

For this particular issue, i tried a lot of things but finally one thing solved the issue.

Steps:

1. after adding an item to Cart, I tried the direct one page URL in the browser. i.e., https://domain.com/onepage
2. It showed issue while reading the `GeoIP.dat`  file.
3. went to console, did

`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data lib/MaxMind` 
 `sudo chmod -R 777 lib/MaxMind`

4. refreshed the page and IT WORKED.

Comment: have you clear all cache and this module enable to admin side? also check module file here \app\design\frontend\base\default\template\opc

Comment: Hey Thanks for comment. I did clear all the cache but still dint have any success. Added an update which resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Proceed to checkout button comes from file `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/link.phtml` Check if it is not commented from here. Also check if there is no css done to hide it.

Usually proceed to checkout is disabled when products in cart are all out of stock. Check for that too.

Comment: thats the one for native one page checkout. The IWD OnePage Checkout has its own templates which overrides the native code. Thanks for trying to help. I have added an update which solved the issue for me.

Comment: Just out of curiosity what version of IWD you were using btw?

Comment: i'm using iwd_onepagecheckout_free - 4.3.0_4

Answer (score 0):

For this particular issue, i tried a lot of things but finally one thing solved the issue.

Steps:

1. after adding an item to Cart, I tried the direct one page URL in the browser. i.e., https://domain.com/onepage/
2. It showed issue while reading the `GeoIP.dat`  file.
3. went to console, did

`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data lib/MaxMind` 
`sudo chmod -R 777 lib/MaxMind`

refreshed the page and IT WORKED.